# erro em importar tabela em banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

estou tentando importar uma tabela mas esta apresentando esse erro.

--

### -- Estrutura da tabela `tb_colaboradores`

CREATE TABLE `tb_colaboradores` (
  `id_colaborador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `acesso` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

## 1046 - Aucune base n'a Ã©tÃ© sÃ©lectionnÃ©e

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de importar uma tabela, verifique se a `database` foi criada e após ela ser criada, clique no nome dela (caso for no phpmyadmin) para entrar na database. Após isso você pode importar.